# Create Phone Number coding challenge

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me what wrong with my code below?

**Write a function that accepts an array of 10 integers (between 0 and 9), that returns a string of those numbers in the form of a phone number.
Example:
createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]) // => returns "(123) 456-7890"
The returned format must be correct in order to complete this challenge.
Don't forget the space after the closing parentheses!**

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
    let firstpart = ""
    let secondpart = ""
    let thirdpart = ""
    for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
      if(i<3){
        firstpart.concat(numbers[i].toString())
      } else if(3<i<6){
        secondpart.concat(numbers[i].toString())
      } else if(i>=6){
        thirdpart.concat(numbers[i].toString())
      }
    }
    return `(${firstpart} ${secondpart}-${thirdpart}`
}

createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

Comment: Forgot `i == 3`? Maybe you better can describe what result you got incorrect? And is it valid syntax? Don't you need `else if (3 <= i && i < 6)`?

Comment: Missing `)` in the format. Did nobody spot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat returns the result of the string and the added string, it does not change the original string. You want `firstpart += numbers[i].toString` or `firststring = firststring.concat(numbers[1].toString)`

The other answer is also correct. Comparisons in the form of a < b < c may not work as expected. If you need to check that a is less than b and b is less than c, do `a < b && b < c`. In your case, the check that the number is less than 3 is redundant. If it were less than 3, the first block would have caught it, so you if statement should be in the form of:

```js
if (i < 3) {
}
else if (i < 6) {
}
else {
}
```

Comment: So I recently learned that the reason for this behavior is that strings may seem like objects, but they are actually primatives. You can call methods on them because when Javascript sees you trying to do a method on a string, it wraps it in a String object then calls that object's method. Afterward, the string object is discarded. (Just additional context)

Answer (score 2):

#### First error

```
firstpart.concat(numbers[i].toString())
```

This statement (as well as the others) just doesn't behave as you expect.
The function concat does not modify the object, it just returns the string obtained by concatenating the two strings. Hence, firstpart never gets modified.
Try this instead:

```
firstpart += numbers[i].toString()
```

#### Second error:

```
3<i<6
```

This is interpreted like so:

- (3 < i) < 6
- (true or false) < 6
- 1 (or 0) < 6
- true

Ternary boolean expressions won't work in JS.
This should fix the issue:

```
i >= 3 && i < 6
```

#### Solution

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
    let firstpart = ""
    let secondpart = ""
    let thirdpart = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (i < 3) {
            firstpart += numbers[i].toString()
        } else if (i >= 3 && i < 6) {
            secondpart += numbers[i].toString()
        } else if (i >= 6) {
            thirdpart += numbers[i].toString()
        }
    }
    return `(${firstpart} ${secondpart}-${thirdpart})`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
  var format = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx";
  
  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  {
    format = format.replace('x', numbers[i]);
  }
  
  return format;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers)
{
  let conCode = numbers.slice(0,3);
  country = conCode.join('');
  let areaCode = numbers.slice(3,6);
  area = areaCode.join('');
  let postCode = numbers.slice(-4);
  post = postCode.join('');
  
  return "(" + country + ")" + " " + area + "-" + post;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
  let fPart='', sPart='', lPart='';
  for(let i =0; i<numbers.length; i++){
     if(i < 3){
        fPart = `${fPart}${numbers[i]}`;
      }
     if(i >= 3 && i < 6){
        sPart = `${sPart}${numbers[i]}`;
      }
     if(i >= 6 && i < 10){
        lPart = `${lPart}${numbers[i]}`;
      }
  }
  return `(${fPart}) ${sPart}-${lPart}`;
}
createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript function takes an array of 10 digits and converts it into a well-formatted phone number string in the format `(XXX) XXX-XXXX`. It does this by joining the digits into a single string and then breaking that string into the required segments using the substring method and concatenating them together with the appropriate characters.

```js
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
  numbers = numbers.join('');
  return '(' + numbers.substring(0, 3) + ') ' 
      + numbers.substring(3, 6) 
      + '-' 
      + numbers.substring(6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
    let firstpart = ""
    let secondpart = ""
    let thirdpart = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (i < 3) {
            firstpart += numbers[i].toString()
        } else if (i >= 3 && i < 6) {
            secondpart += numbers[i].toString()
        } else if (i >= 6) {
            thirdpart += numbers[i].toString()
        }
    }
    return `(${firstpart}) ${secondpart}-${thirdpart}`
}
```

Comment: It might be more useful for other readers that you also explain why your code works compared to code from the question, @kestone-dennis.

Answer (score -1):

```
const createPhoneNumber = function (arr) {
  const number = `(${arr.slice(0, 3).join('')}) ${arr
    .slice(3, 6)
    .join('')}-${arr.slice(7).join('')}`;
  console.log(number);
};

createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]);
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping code that may fix the problem, you should _explain_ what that code does, and why it fixes OP's problem. See [answer]

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements the other answers.